# PhpStorm - Autodownload certain folders

Tags: phpstorm

I've set up PhpStorm to auto-deploy changed files to the vagrant box.

However, I run the build scripts in the box, and I can't count the times I shipped some module without copying back (downloading) those compressed JavaScript files, out of vagrant, into my local working directory.

Is there a way to make PhpStorm monitor the deployment server, and download changed files?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make PhpStorm monitor the deployment server, and download changed files?

There is no auto-download.

The IDE is build around "local code first" idea where local is the source and any remote is just a copy.

If you need to download remote stuff I suggest to manually use `Sync With Deployed` action from Deployment menu: it allows to manually sync files and folders both ways: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/deploying-applications.html

---

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1284 *I guess* (as it's about syncing remote to local)... Watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.